# Serialize C# class directly to SQL server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, serialization

can anyone suggest the best way to serialize data (a class actually) to a DB?

I am using SQL server 2008 but i presume i need to serialize the class to a string / or other data type before storing in the database?

I presume that this field needs to be text or binary??

Does SQL server 2008 (or .net 3.5) support serializing directly tothe database ??

Any help really appreciated

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can xml serialize the class into an xml field.  We use this all the time for exception logging in an ETL.

Using the XmlSerializer you may want a helper method somewhere which serializes the class to a string...

```
public static string SerializeToXml<T>(T value)
{
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    return writer.ToString();
}
```

Then just put the string into the db like any other.

Comment: Why did I not think about using a generic for this? *face palm*

Comment: @tom - because there's no need for a generic here. You could equally well use "object value" and then call "value.GetType()" when constructing the serializer.

Comment: But how to make sure that my serialized XML text length is not longer than available field length in SQL Server?

Comment: I like this approach, but I am having hard time deserializing the XML.  I want to determin the type from the XML and deserialize back to original object...

Comment: Added a method that will de-serialize the string.

Answer (score 20):

The **best** way to store data in a database is in columns (per property), so that it is queryable and indexable. ORM tools will help with this.

However, it *is* also possible to serialize a class as a CLOB/BLOB (`varchar(max)`/`varbinary(max)` etc).

It this is what you want, avoid anything implementation-specific or version-intolerant; so in particular, don't use `BinaryFormatter`. Anything contract-based should work; `XmlSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer`, etc. Or for fast binary, protobuf-net might be worth a look.

But I stress; columns would be better.

Comment: marc  - why you advise tyo avoid BinaryFormatter ? it is the lesser in size... Also , how does Contract base improve data being saved in db ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir it can have severe problems with versioning, due to including full type names (including assemblies) etc, and being field-dependent. It also isn't the smallest by a long shot. I would usually advise protobuf-net which is usually less space *and* avoids all the versioing problems - but I'm somewhat biased.

Comment: i see, but still dont understand the `due to including full type names`.. whats wrong with that ? whats wrong if im storing the type  (example : `List<Person>()`)...can you please explain in a word or 2 ? thanks.

Comment: @Namir because it is actually "Some.Namespace.Person, Some.Assembly.dll,1.0.23.4" which can be a problem if you refactor (I've seen this hurt people many many times), it is .NET specific (can't load in another platform, and depends on the field names (better hope nobody switches to automatically implemented properties, as that will break). It has a habit of serializing too much (via events), and leading to situations where (without large hassle) you ***cannot*** get your data back. Oh, and it neither particularly small not particularly fast.

Answer (score 3):

Without generics (better sollution)

```
public static string SerializeToXml(object value)
{
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(value.GetType());
  serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
  return writer.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've serialized objects as XML and thrown those into the database just fine.  Since we knew the max amount of text we used the varchar(max) datatype instead of getting into TEXT or Binary formats.

This was a OLTP web application and one thing we found was that using a column with an xml datatype invoked some significant cpu usage as the xml was validated on every insert. In our case the xml was never queried for anything so not having the xml query capabilities worked out ok for us.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of options:

Runtime serialization, serializable objects are marked with the 
Serializable attribute, in which case the IFormatter class does all the work of 
serialization. A serializable object can ISerializable, but then you will
need to implement the GetObjectData( ) method. The problem with runtime serialization is that program reading the xml data needs to have
the knowledge of the CLR types.

Xml serialization: Unline runtime serialization, you will get good interoperability in this case.
The XmlSerializer type contains the methods Serialize( ) and Deserialize( ), thus 
any object can be serialized to XML and saved into the database and when you retreive it back, you
can deserialize it easily.

To read data from the database, you can use the SqlCommand class 
method that executes SQL queries, namely ExecuteXmlReader( ). 
ExecuteXmlReader( ) returns an instance of XmlReader and that will read your xml data.

Answer (score -1):

Check out Linq-to-SQL  ([questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq-to-sql), [resource on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)) or other [O-R Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orm) options.