# Importing XML Data From XML File To SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, xml, forms

I'm new to C# and have been working on learning database's. Currently I'm trying to import data from a XML document that has items stored as follows:

```
   <CityData>
        <City>Ada</City>
        <County>Olmsted</County>
        <AreaCode>507</AreaCode>
        <Founded>1900</Founded>
        <CityWebSite>www.adacity.com</CityWebSite>
        <Population>1200</Population>
        <Zipcode>56996</Zipcode>
        <ZipcodeMax>57656</ZipcodeMax>
    </CityData>
```

I'm trying to save each data collection to a different row in a SQL Express database. I've been able to store other information in the database, I just don't know how to do this with a XML document. The database is stored locally on my machine along with the C# program I'm writing. I have a new table with columns named and ordered like the XML documents schema. The tutorials I'm finding online are for .asp programs. Has anyone ever done this? This is a C# Forms Program.

Comment: Which version of .net are you using?  I ask because LINQ can make this pretty easy.

Comment: Please don't add "C#" to the ends of your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: I'm using Visual C# Studio 2008 with SQL Server Express. I'll look up LINQ now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do your job. please make sure to replace **filePath\fileName.xml** with full path to the xml and change **/dataroot/CityData** (at the bottom) as per your xml. Also sql should be able to access the file.

```
Declare @xml XML

Select  @xml  = 
CONVERT(XML,bulkcolumn,2) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'filePath\fileName.xml',SINGLE_BLOB) AS X

SET ARITHABORT ON

Insert into [YourTableName] 
        (
            City,County,AreaCode,Founded,CityWebSite,[Population],Zipcode,ZipcodeMax
        )

    Select 
        P.value('City[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS City,
        P.value('County[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS County,
        P.value('AreaCode[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS AreaCode,
        P.value('Founded[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS Founded,
        P.value('CityWebSite[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS CityWebSite,
        P.value('Population[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS Population,
        P.value('Zipcode[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS Zipcode,
        P.value('ZipcodeMax[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS ZipcodeMax,

    From @xml.nodes('/dataroot/CityData') PropertyFeed(P)
```

Comment: Won't this only work if the XML file only has one CityData element?

Comment: Maybe my inexperience is holding me back but I don't have access to "Declare", I can use Select, I don't think I'm missing any using statements at the top. Is there something I'm suppose to do to get Declare @xml XML?

Comment: @CFL_Jeff I am assuming that CityData as a child node of dataroot.

Comment: This is a query and should be running on sql server query window or you could convert this to a stored procedure.

Comment: @Indikaf What if there are multiple CityData elements in the file?

Comment: @CFL_Jeff Assuming xml data is like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><dataroot> <CityData><City>London</City>...</CityData><CityData><City>Paris</City>...</CityData>...<dataroot>`

Comment: The xml data does follow these properties: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8?> <CityData><City>London</City></CityData><CityData>Paris</CityData>

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2008 C#, and in my Database Explorer I see a sub folder called Stored Procedures, do I write the function there? Sorry for being so much trouble but I've never seen anything that adds a new stored procedure.

Comment: The above code says Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Declare' and Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'From' when I try to create the stored procedure.

Comment: SQL Server 2008, or is the version somewhere else?

Comment: I figured out the Declare syntax error but now I'm having problems with "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'From'.

Comment: I'm trying to use the built in stored procedure area under the database explorer in Visual Studio C#.

Comment: You can easily do int on SQL Server Management Studio. `Start: Programs\MS Sql Server ...\MS Server Management Studio` And then logon to your instance (ex: local). Click on `New Query`>> copy the query on to it (comment insert section for testing)>> Hit Execute button. Provided that sql has access to file path + xml has <dataroot> as the parent node (ie; all <?xml .../><dataroot> ...all city data nodes ...</dataroot> ) it should give you the results. if yes then uncomment insert bit and hit Execute. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

First, you [deserialize](http://web.archive.org/web/20081025025509/http://quickduck.com/blog/2008/02/18/persisting-objects-into-database-using-xml-serialization/) the XML into C# objects.

Then, you [serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212555/serialize-c-sharp-class-directly-to-sql-server) the data from objects into the database.

Lucky you, [C# makes XML Deserialization a snap](http://web.archive.org/web/20081117192106/http://quickduck.com/blog/2008/02/15/using-xmlreader-to-go-from-sql-result-set-to-a-list-of-objects/).