# C# Sending an object as parameter to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

I want to send my object(with multiple smaller objects within) to a stored procedure.

I have already implemented this using XML where we convert the object to XML in c# and fetch values from this XML in SQL.

```
Class A
{
    public B field1;
    public C field2;
    public D field3;
}
```

The issue is the process of conversion to XML back and forth takes too much time. Is there any faster way to pass an object to the stored procedure?

Any links to a better approach will be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the XML serialization code? What is "too much time"? It usually shouldn't take a noticeable amount of time (but knowing the full object definition/XML example might help).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize C# class directly to SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212555/serialize-c-sharp-class-directly-to-sql-server)

Comment: Have you looked into JSON?